# como obtener valor de label html del lado del servidor ASP.NET c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, web

De mi lado cliente tengo un select de html donde al cambiar el indice se cambia un label de html con jquery

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("select[name = sreport]").change(function () {
            var selected = $("option:selected", this).text();
            if (selected == "Seleccione el tipo de Reporte") {
                $('#divtxtbuscar').hide();
                $('#divbuscar').hide();
                $("label[for = sreport]").text("");
               
            }
            else if (selected == "Por Operación") {
                $('#divtxtbuscar').show();
                $('#divbuscar').show();
                $("label[for = sreport]").text("Folio de Operación:");
            }
            else if (selected == "Por No. de Parte") {
                $('#divtxtbuscar').show();
                $('#divbuscar').show();
                $("label[for = sreport]").text("No. de Parte:");
            }
            else if (selected == "Por Maquina") {
                $('#divtxtbuscar').show();
                $('#divbuscar').show();
                $("label[for = sreport]").text("No. de Maquina:");
            }
            else if (selected == "Por Empleado") {
                $('#divtxtbuscar').show();
                $('#divbuscar').show();
                $("label[for = sreport]").text("No. de Empleado:");
            }


        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Tipo de Reporte:</label>
<select id="cmb" name="sreport" class="form-control" >
  <option value="seleccionar">Seleccione el tipo de Reporte</option>
  <option value="operacion">Por Operación</option>
  <option value="parte">Por No. de Parte</option>
  <option value="maquina">Por Maquina</option>
  <option value="empleado">Por Empleado</option>
</select>
<div id="divtxtbuscar" class="form-group" style="display: none">
  <label id="lblsreport" for="sreport" runat="server"></label><br />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtbuscar" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Ahora lo que quiero es tomar el valor de mi label del lado de mi servidor (C#) y guardarlo en una variable pero no puedo usar .value, uso innertext y no regresa nada.
Que otra opción tengo?

O bien de que modo puedo cambiar un label de asp en vez de uno de html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tomarlo usando el .value como mencioans deberias definir el `runat="server"` en el `<select>` de esta forma si le defines un id al combo podrias accederlo como un htmlcontrol

[HtmlSelect Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect(v=vs.110).aspx)

Sino la alternativa es que te olvides de los eventos de asp.net y envies usando jquery usando $.ajax invocando un webmethod en el servidor web
Pero si haces esto ya no usarias evento ni necesitas acceder a los controles en el servidor ya que envias los datos desde el cliente mediante json, como explico aqui

[[jQuery] DropDownList anidados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/04/jquery-dropdownlist-anidados-nested.html)

Answer (score 2):

En `Webforms` los nombres cambian según como se encuentren estructurados, por ejemplo:

Le das:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEcho2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Y renderiza:

```
<input id="Text1" name="ctl00$MasterPageBody$ctl00$txtEcho2" />
```

Lo que debes hacer en tu JavaScript es algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var miVariableEnJavaScript = '<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>';
  //Con esto obtienes el valor
  $(miVariableEnJavaScript).value;
</script>
```

Este JavaScript debe estar en un archivo `.aspx` para que reconozca los `<%... %>`

Comment: a que te refieres con renderizar?

Comment: al código fuente que el navegador genera :D

Comment: mi pagina es aspx, sin embargo no me reconoce la variable que pongo entre '<%=... %>';

Comment: qué error te aparece?